# Itk Region Growing seed Points

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vtk, itk

I am trying to segment brain vessels so i am using `ITK Region Growing algorithm.` I am very confused about the setting of `seed point to segment the brain vessels`.I have contrast injected CT data set .How should set the seed point so that i can segment the vessels only using volume rendering?

Answer (score 1):

Region growing is not the best algorithm for vessel segmentation. You should look at [TubeTK](http://www.tubetk.org/), particularly at [SegmentTubes](https://github.com/KitwareMedical/ITKTubeTK/tree/master/apps/SegmentTubes) application. It can be a good starting point for your problem. Look at the [tests](https://github.com/KitwareMedical/ITKTubeTK/blob/master/apps/SegmentTubes/Testing/CMakeLists.txt) for examples of how to invoke it.

Comment: I have complied itk with `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = Release 
ITK_LEGACY_SILENT = On 
ITK_WRAP_PYTHON = On 
Module_MinimalPathExtraction = On ` but cmake is showing error as `CMake Error at CMake/ITKModuleRemote.cmake:142 (message):
  error: could not find git for clone of MinimalPathExtraction
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  Modules/Remote/MinimalPathExtraction.remote.cmake:2 (itk_fetch_module)
  Modules/Remote/CMakeLists.txt:6 (include)`

Comment: I have downloaded `MinimalPathExtraction` module from github.How should i add it to itk?

Comment: My plan is to apply `vesselness filter` first ,then thresholding,then region growing .Are these steps enough to get atleast the main brain vessels without bone?Can you suggest any other idea?

Comment: Vesselness+thresholding OR Vesselness+region growing make sense. You don't need both thresholding and region growing.

You need to have `git` installed and in the path so ITK can use it to clone remote modules.

Comment: i tried vesselness+thresholding but it is not giving the exact output i want.I asked this question for doing vesselness+region growing.i will definitely follow your response .thanks